# Powershell Multidimensional Arrays output everything

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to read out certain things from a 2D array with Write-Host and then make the whole thing readable with a join, but it doesn't work. Maybe someone could help me out. It would be nice. That's how I would do it

```
Write-Host ($Output[0..-1][0] -join("|"))
```

Comment: As an aside: Note that `$Output[0..-1]` is the same as `$Output[0, -1]`, i.e. you're extracting only the first and the last element.

Comment: @mklement0 `$Output[0, -1]` will behave wildly differently between `[object[][]]` and `[object[,]]` :)

Comment: Good point, @MathiasR. - I was focused on the first kind, i.e. _jagged_ arrays - which in PowerShell are far more common than the latter, i.e. true multi-dimensional arrays. Either way, `0..-1` as the index expression is the same as `0, -1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The following assumes that you're using a **jagged array** (arrays nested inside an outer array), which in .NET is slightly different from a ***multidimensional array***. See the example at the bottom for a real 2D array*.

Unpack the outer array with the pipeline, then invoke the `-join` operation against the values in each inner array one by one, and then finally join the resulting strings together:

```
# create jagged (nested) 3x3 array from nested array literals
$Output = @(
  @(1,2,3),
  @(4,5,6),
  @(7,8,9)
)

Write-Host (($Output |% { $_ -join '|' }) -join "`n")
```

Which would print the following multiline string to the host buffer:

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

If you want separate strings per inner array (eg. because you want to use them later for something else), remove the outer `-join` operation:

```
$rows = $Output |% { $_ -join '|' }
```

---

If `$Output` indeed holds a *multidimensional array*, then you'll have to do a bit of work to unpack each "row":

```
# create and populate a proper 3x3 multidimensional array with the same values as above
$Output = [int[,]]::new(3, 3)
$i = $j = 0
1..9 |ForEach-Object {
  $i = [Math]::DivRem($_ - 1, 3, [ref]$j)
  $Output[$i, $j] = $_
}

# unpack array and print values
Write-Host (@(
  for($i = 0; $i -lt $Output.GetLength(0); $i++) {
    $rowValues = for($j = 0; $j -lt $Output.GetLength(1); $j++) {
      $Output[$i, $j]
    }

    $rowValues -join '|'
  }
) -join "`n")
```